# Calling segue programmatically not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am trying to make a splash screen. I have a view that has a background image being drawn onto it and then another view I want to transition to after a few seconds. I am trying to use the following code:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showApp", sender: self)
```

I created a segue between the two views by ctrl+dragging a line from one to the other. I set the segue's identifier to "showApp".

When I run the code nothing happens and there are no errors. Any ideas?

Here is the controller for the splash screen:

```
class SplashViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sleep(2)

        // THIS DOES NOTHING:
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showApp", sender: self)

        // THIS AS SUGGESTED ALSO DOES NOTHING:
        var otherViewController:UIViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("test") as UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(otherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`?

Comment: in viewDidLoad() of the controller

Comment: Do you actually have the navigation controller implemented? Need to know more information.

Comment: does it require a navigation controller? i just have a View Controller right now

Comment: Yes, you need a navigation controller in order to use segue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you need a navigation controller in order to use segue.

Highlight your SplashViewController object inside the Storyboard and go to

**Editor -> Embeded In -> Navigation Controller**

[image]

After that, remove the code suggested by Clement and try running the project again, you should get the result that you expected.