# Presenting UINavigationController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am presenting a loading screen where I do not want the navigation bar to be shown. So I use

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true`

Which does the trick and hides the navigation bar. But when I want to show the navigation bar, I want to animate it in.

I have tried using this code but the bar does not appear.

`self.navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)`

After running the above code the bar is still hidden, how can I show/animate the bar?

Comment: What controller or controllers are these statements in, and where do you call them? How is you loading screen getting put on screen?

Answer (score 5):

I think your method is correct already. You just need to know where to put the code. Try the following code.

**Code for ViewController 1**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToScreen2", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**Code for ViewController 2**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Update Answer:**

I am able to unhide the navigation bar using the following code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Screen shot of the implementation:-

[image]

Comment: I am not changing VC's, I am hiding the nav bar in `viewDidLoad` and am waiting for a JSON response. Once I get the data back I want to close the loading screen then show the navigation bar.

Comment: See the updated answer, I can unhide it using a button without a problem. I just tested. I think you are doing something wrong. May be you do not implement the Navigation Controller properly on the storyboard. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777465/calling-segue-programatically-not-working/25778229#25778229